# Compact subsets of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

I am trying to to prove that f: X --> Y is continuous on X if and only if f is continuous on every compact subset of X. X and Y are metric spaces.

**How do I show that every point of X belongs to some compact subset of X?**

Answer (score 2):

*Hint* We know $f$ is continuous iff for every $x_n\to x$ in $X$ it follows that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ in $Y$. Now pick a convergent sequence $\{x_n\}$ and prove $A=\{x_n\}\cup\left\{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n\right\}$ is compact.   What does it mean that $f$ is continuous over $A$? What do you conclude?

Comment: Is X the union of all such A's?

Comment: @user1234 No, there might be non convergent sequences in $X$, but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: Your hint is really good...let me think more about it because I still have not figured out...

Comment: Are we proving that f is sequentially continuous?

Comment: For any x in X, let {xn} be a sequence that converges to x, then the set {xn} union {x} is compact. Let A be the intersection of this set and X, we don't know anything about A, right?

Comment: Is it true that for any x in X, x is either an isolated point or x is a point such that there is a sequence in X that converges to x?

Comment: @user1234 It is always true there is a sequence in $X$ that converges to $x$: $\{x,x,x,\ldots\}$.

Comment: So for every x in X, there exists a sequence in X that converges to x. This sequence together with x forms a compact subset of X. By assumption, f is continuous on this compact set, hence f is continuous at x. Since x is arbitrary, f is continuous on X. Am I understanding your idea right? Sorry for asking so many questions that you have to come back to this so many times. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1234 No. The statement "$f$ is continuous at $x\in X$" is very different from "$f$ is continuous over the set $\{x\}$." What I am trying to make you do is using that $f$ is continuous over every compact subset of $X$; show $f$ has the property that  whenever $x_n\to x$ in $X$, then $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ in $Y$. This means precisely that $f$ is continuous over all $X$. We're not interested in arbitrary sequences of $X$, rather, we're interested in the convergent sequences.

Comment: So for any sequence {xn} in X that converges to x in X, the sequence and x form a compact subset of X. Because f is continuous on this compact set, f is sequentially continuous on this set. Hence, f(xn) -> f(x) in Y? (I feel sth not right here?) Since this is true for any convergent sequence in X, f is continuous on X?

Answer (score 0):

A finite set is always compact.  What if $f$ is compact at every $\{x\}$ for every $x\in X$?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a metric space, automatically every singleton set (to be more general, every finite set) becomes compact (Singleton being complete and totally bounded). One of the parts is trivial. If $f$ is continuous on $X$, then so is its restriction to any subset of $X$ under the relative metric. On the other hand, if it is continuous on every singleton, it may not really mean that it is continuous on the whole space.

Comment: I agree with what you said, "if it is continuous on every singleton, it may not really mean that it is continuous on the whole space."